# Taking a C# sha512 hash and compare it in php

Tags: c#, php, passwords, sha512

I have looked and found code to take a PHP sha512 hash and match it inside C#. I am currently looking for a way to go from a hash that was made in C# and get the same result in PHP. We are slowly moving away from asp.net to PHP and need a way to check our passwords in the database. Here is the C# code used to make the hash.

```
// Create a hash from a pwd and salt using sha512
    public static string CreatePasswordHash(string _password, string _salt)
    {
        string saltAndPwd = String.Concat(_password, _salt);
        SHA512 sha512 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();

        byte[] sha512Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(saltAndPwd);

        byte[] cryString = sha512.ComputeHash(sha512Bytes);

        string hashedPwd = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < cryString.Length; i++)
        {
            hashedPwd += cryString[i].ToString("X");
        }

        return hashedPwd;
    }
```

In PHP I have tried to get it to match but it is off by just a few bytes it seems.

```
function CreatePasswordHash($_password, $_salt)
    {            
        $saltAndPwd = $_password . $_salt;            
        $hashedPwd = hash('sha512', $saltAndPwd);      
        return strtoupper($hashedPwd);
    }
```

When using the above with the same salt and password here is the results I get.
The first result is from C#, and the second result is from PHP:

```
60BB73FDA3FF7A444870C6D0DBC7C6966F8D5AD632B0A02762E0283051D7C54A5F4B01571D1A5BC8C689DBC411FEB92158383A56AFC6AE6074696AF36E16    
60BB73FDA3FF7A444870C6D0DBC7C609066F8D5AD632B0A02762E0283051D7C54A5F4B001571D1A5BC8C689DBC411FEB092158383A56AFC6AE6074696AF36E16
```

Any ideas on why these are not matching up? Does it have to do with endian byte order?

Comment: Is it perhaps a mismatch of encodings?

Comment: Your C# code was broken, and swallowed some `0`s. But you should migrate away from plain SHA-512, since it's insufficient for password hashing. Use bcrypt with sufficient iterations instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

`hashedPwd += cryString[i].ToString("X2");`

Editing PHP:

```
function CreatePasswordHash($_password, $_salt)
{
    $saltAndPwd = $_password . $_salt;
    $hashedPwd = hash('sha512', $saltAndPwd);

    $hex_strs = str_split($hashedPwd,2);

    foreach($hex_strs as &$hex) {
        $hex = preg_replace('/^0/', '', $hex);
    }
    $hashedPwd = implode('', $hex_strs);

    return strtoupper($hashedPwd);
}
```

Comment: This makes it works by editing C# I need to make it work by editing php. The passwords are already in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The C# print out is not including leading zeros.

Replace

```
hashedPwd += cryString[i].ToString("X");
```

with

```
hashedPwd += cryString[i].ToString("X2");
```

Comment: This makes it works by editing C# I need to make it work by editing php. The passwords are already in the database.

Comment: @user1698686 If they are already in the database it is probably best to fix your code properly and request a password reset for the users that it affects if possible.

Comment: I agree, though I am not sure I can get the CEO to agree to this course of action. Though we may be able to do something were we fix it each time they log in. Remove the old password hash and replace it with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you use the same character encoding in C# and PHP. GetBytes returns different results, depending on the encoding. System.Text.Encoding.Default depends on the localization of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [open_ssl_digest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-digest.php)

```
echo openssl_digest($saltAndPwd, 'sha512');
```

if you have PHP >= 5.3

You could also use the [hash_algos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) function to see which algorithms are supported in your system.

HTH

Comment: open_ssl_digest produces the same result